# Can I use using inside a fnc def?

Tags: c++, templates

I've a construct of this form:

```
template<class X>
struct Base
{
  X get_data()
  {
    return X();
  }
};

template<class X>
struct Derived : Base<X>
{
  X do()
  {
    auto v = get_data();//this get is from Base
  }

};
```

I tried to use this get as it is shown but I was getting error : there are no arguments to 'get_data' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'get_data' must be available [-fpermissive]|
Ok so I've tried:

```
X do()
{
  using Base<T>::get_data;
  auto v = get_data();//this get is from Base
}
```

And I've got the following `error: 'Derived<T>::Base' is not a namespace`. Now, here I've got a problem, because as a matter of fact formally Base being a struct is a namespace (special form of) but anyway, I declared using `Base<T>::get_data;` outside of any fnc and this compiles. So the Q is: Is that a compiler error or using 'using declaration' is permitted inside a fnc body?

Comment: Try `using Base<X>::get_data;`.

Comment: @KerrekSB sorry I didn't make myself clear enough. There is using Base<X>::get_data construct.

Comment: I see. That wasn't clear because your formatting was broken, so that piece was invisible.

Comment: `do` is a C++ keyword; you mustn't use it as a function name.

Comment: @KerrekSB sorry it's actually do_it.

Comment: A struct is not formally a namespace. The compiler is correct, that's not allowed. Although I agree it would be useful sometimes.

Comment: @AlanStokes struct is form of a namespace.

Comment: @smallB feel free to think of a struct as like a namespace, but that doesn't mean it is one. See 7.3 in the standard.

Comment: @AlanStokes I've said is 'form/sort of' a namespace, not in the formal sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`using` directives for base class member names only make sense on the class level, where they serve to make names of base class members visible that might otherwise be hidden.

They do not make sense at function scope, and thus aren't allowed there.

What you can do is this:

```
struct Derived : public Base<X>
{
  using Base<X>::get_data;
  //...
};
```

(This is only sensible here because of your template context and the fact that `get_data()` doesn't depend on any template parameters. In an ordinary class, you wouldn't need this at all if you aren't deliberately hiding the function.)

At function scope, the only `using` directives that are allowed are those that bring in names from other *namespaces* for the purpose of argument-dependent lookup.

Also note that `do` is a C++ keyword.

Comment: I disagree that using 'declaration' not **directive** as you've mentioned doesn't make sense w/r to class members. Didn't I just show you one use where it makes sense? I just wanted in this one fnc to access the get_data. Not in any other.

Comment: `using` isn't "telling the compiler which function to use"; rather, it is about making names visible. There's still ADL and overload resolution to consider. If you just flat-out want to call a base class function, just qualify the function name directly.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
using Base<T>::get_data;
```

with

```
using Base<X>::get_data;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
auto v = this->get_data();
```

Comment: my question is if it is compiler error that it doesn't let me use using declaration inside fnc body, not how to resolve this, because I've already resolved that myself as you read from my OP.